# Java HTTPClient File Upload Server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, file-upload

edit: solved below

So I need to create a server that can be used to upload files to and then serve those files back upon request. After some research it seemed like using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) on the client side and [FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) on the server side with a Tomcat servlet would be a good way to accomplish this task. After pulling from various example sources I have come up with the following code for the client:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class Client {
    static String url = "http://localhost:8080";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            File file = new File("2048.zip");
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);

            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            builder.addPart("file", fileBody);
            HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            request.setEntity(entity);

            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            try {
                client.execute(request);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        //list_files();
    }
}
```

And this for the servlet code:

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

        if (isMultipart) {
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

            try {
                List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();

                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                        String fileName = item.getName();

                        String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                        File path = new File(root);
                        if (!path.exists()) {
                            boolean status = path.mkdirs();
                        }

                        File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
                        System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        item.write(uploadedFile);
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This in the web-xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>fileservlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>servlet.FileServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fileservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/fileservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

When I try to run the client I just get hit with these errors until it times out.

```
Dec 04, 2017 4:08:34 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8080: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
Dec 04, 2017 4:08:34 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8080
```

This is my first time working with servlets and Tomcat so I'm unsure if there's a configuration issue in eclipse or an actual issue with the code.

Edit: Okay so for the first time I've managed to get the file to send through the client and be saved by the server. The first thing I had to do was ensure that the "url" matched the correct servlet extension. When I launched the servlet in eclipse it automatically opened `http://localhost:8080/FileServlet/FileServlet` so this is what I used in the client when sending the file. I also uncommented a part of the servers.xml file having to do with thread pool.

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
```

Also I used the code straight from the HttpClient example page [for multipart sending](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/examples/org/apache/http/examples/entity/mime/ClientMultipartFormPost.java).

Comment: Have you verified the address and port that Tomcat is listening on? Is it using localhost, or the external IP address of the machine?

Comment: @ThrawnCA When launching the servlet in eclipse it is using localhost and Tomcat is running http on 8080.

Comment: How about tomcat logs? Maybe worth take a look since an IO exception was reported by the client. Common location of tomcat log file is `/var/lib/tomcat/logs/catalina.out`.

Comment: @RubenO.Chiavone The logs in the tomcat installation are empty but since I'm running it in eclipse I checked the logs there and everytime I run the client the server log shows several lines of `127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2017:18:19:05 -0600] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 951.` So it seems like the POST requests are getting there?

Comment: You need to add more logging to the servlet to debug this, at least to check whether it was even entered. If the upload is large you may just be violating Tomcat's upload limit, which is configurable in server.xml or somewhere.